# Inverse of Poisson process.

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, poisson-process

Let $N(T)\sim \text{Pois}(\lambda T)$. My question is:

$$\lim_{T\to\infty}E\Big[\frac{1}{N(T)}\Big]= \; ?$$

Is it zero or $\infty$?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: I suggest you start with $E\Big[\frac{1}{N(T)}\Big]$ for fixed $T$

Comment: Find the distribution and the mean and take the limit? Did you try anything

Comment: $1/N(T)$ is not defined if $N(T)=0$.  So $E[1/N(T)]$ is not defined, since, for any $T>0$, there is always a positive probability that $N(T)=0$. Nevertheless, assuming $\lambda>0$, for any $\epsilon>0$ we have $\lim_{T\rightarrow\infty}E[\frac{1}{\epsilon + N(T)}]=0$ (for example, by the bounded convergence theorem).